# AuthenticationError in reading mail using IMAP protocol using JavaMail

Tags: authentication, jakarta-mail, imap, putty

I am trying to read emails from XXX domain using Java Mail API. I am able to login and read the email using IMAPS protocol using PUTTY from server.

However from Java, I am getting Authentication Error:

[image]

Following is the screenshot where I am able to connect from PUTTY:

[image]

Following is my Code:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.put("mail.imap.host", "hostname");
            properties.put("mail.imap.port", "993");

            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties, new javax.mail.Authenticator()
            {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
                {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication("username", "password");
                }
            });

            Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
            store.connect("username", "password");
```

What does making it stop to read mail from Java ?

> Internally, mail domain is using outlook exchange server.
>
> Username being passed is full xxxx@domain.com.

Comment: Please do not put errors in screenshot, they can not be searched, and are almost impossible to read on mobile.  Use copy/paste and format accordingly.  Also please provide the FULL stack trace.

Comment: Why are you setting pop3 host when using imaps?

Comment: Thanks Max. Error log is that much only. Pop3 is by mistake, it is using IMAP only. I will update code.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the property settings; they have no effect since you're using imaps.  And you can [get rid of the Authenticator](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes) since you're passing the username and password explicitly.

You need to pass the host explicitly as well, otherwise it's connecting to localhost, which may be why it's failing.  Look at the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) to see what it's actually doing.  If that doesn't solve your problem, post the debug output.

Comment: I agree Bill, but even without Authenticator it is returning error only. This code is running on different server on which, putty is able to connect. I am passing code to devops to run on that server and it returns this error.

Comment: Post the code without the Authenticator.  Your code above is setting properties for "imap" but using "imaps", so the properties have no effect.  And post the JavaMail debug output.